# How to use keyword "this" with DOM manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I'm learning about using keyword "this" with DOM manipulation in JavaScript and I have a missunderstand. Maybe someone can help me to understand it.

For example I have this simple program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <p class="second">No excuses</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="three">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

script.js:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 

console.log("This 1 = " + this);

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        console.log("This 2 = " + this);
        input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    } 
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function changeClass() {
        this.classList.toggle("done");
        console.log("This 3 = " + this);
}

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("click", changeClass)
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick)

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress)
```

It is a simple list, and you can add new elements in the list, also you can change the class of an element when you click on an element of the list.

When I  refresh the browser I get in the console: **This 1 = [object Window]**

After that I type a letter in the box and click the "Enter" button and I get in the console: **This 2 = [object Window]**. So, the object is still "Window".

After that I click on an element from the list and I get in the console: **This 3 = [object HTMLLIElement]**. I see that the object is changed from Window to HTMLLIElement.

I don't understand when the object is changed from Window to HTMLLIElement. Why the object for This 2 is Window and the object for This 3 is HTMLLIElement. Thank you!

Comment: You're calling the function like `createListElement();`, there's no context involved in the function invocation, i.e. you're not calling a method, you're calling a function.

Comment: @HMR—that's unnecessary. Functions added as listeners with *addEventListener* have the element set to *this* by the handler by default.

Answer (score 2):

> When I refresh the browser I get in the console: This 1 = [object Window]

In global code, *this* is set to the global (window in a browser) object.

> After that I type a letter in the box and click the "Enter" button and I get in the console: This 2 = [object Window]. So, the object is still "Window".

When the function is called, *this* is not set in the call so it defaults to the global/window object. In strict mode code, it would be *undefined*.

> After that I click on an element from the list and I get in the console: This 3 = [object HTMLLIElement]. I see that the object is changed from Window to HTMLLIElement.

When a function added as a listener by *addEventListener* is called, its *this* is set to the element the listener is set on, as if by:

```
changeClass.call(element, event)
```

The related event is passed as the first argument.

> I don't understand when the object is changed from Window to HTMLLIElement. Why the object for This 2 is Window and the object for This 3 is HTMLLIElement.

*this* is a parameter of an execution context that is set when the context is created. It can be set in the call or using *bind*, or lexically in arrow functions (i.e. adopted from the outer execution context). See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?s=1%7C1046.3390)

Comment: Thans for reply! You said that: “When a function added as a listener by addEventListener is called, its this is set to the element the listener is set on”.. so it’s this is set to “li” element… but I want to ask you something, in the other case, when I type a letter and click the “Enter” button, so the addListAfterClick function is called and it is also a function added as a listener by addEventListener.. why its this isn’t set to “button” element?

Comment: @gaby—I've updated your post to change the code to a runnable snippet and added a console.log to *addListAfterClick*. As you can see, its *this* is the button when called from the button's listener.